# ADO pipeline breaking when using 'buildx' plugin to build image

Tags: .net, docker, azure-pipelines, ado, buildx

I am looking for any input to an issue I am experiencing in my ADO pipeline. Below is an example of the first part of the Dockerfile (all that is needed for demonstration) that keeps failing:

```
FROM harbor.xyz.biz/foo/bar/sdk:6.0-alpine AS publish
ENV IS_DOCKER=true
WORKDIR /src

COPY . ./
WORKDIR /src/SpecChannelAirport.Database.Deploy

RUN dotnet restore --configfile ../NuGet.config
RUN dotnet build --no-restore
RUN dotnet publish
```

Now when I set the ENV_VAR `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0` then the pipeline will build the image just fine and without issue; this is because it is using the legacy `docker build`, which is technically deprecated functionality. However, when this value is set to `1`, which it is by default, then the `docker-buildx` is used, and it causes a very generic error to occur on the last line of the Dockerfile:

```
 > [7/7] RUN dotnet publish:
------
Dockerfile:10
--------------------
   8 |     RUN dotnet restore --configfile ../NuGet.config
   9 |     RUN dotnet build --no-restore
  10 | >>> RUN dotnet publish
  11 |     
  12 |     # FROM harbor.xyz.biz/foo/bar/server:2019
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to prepare urqxwwwnadtw7fx2jwt6eszan as u720dwirlzaast49cej32ujs1: invalid argument
```

I am using `buildx-v0.10.4.linux-amd64` plugin (installed at path `/usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins/`) from [github](https://github.com/docker/buildx/releases/tag/v0.10.4), on my build agent which is an Ubuntu 20.04 docker container, with Docker version 23.0.1 and Docker Compose version 2.17.2.

I was not able to find much in the way of this issue online and am not exactly sure what it could be. If I comment out the last line of the Dockerfile, it will build fine, even when using the `buildx` plugin, so I feel that something has to be going on between the way that the legacy `build` and the current `buildx` is interacting or affecting the way that the `dotnet publish` command is operating.

Does anyone have any ideas or insight to this kind of problem?